# Error while trying to compile a DLL with a static class function in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I am trying to take some functions that I've made and tested with in a standalone application. Now that I am trying to make a DLL I am getting a few errors stating that the function has been redefined and that the return parameters don't match. This seems to be the only time I am getting these errors, I've tested it by removing this class and it compiles fine as well as the stand-alone app with a main.cpp referencing these directly. Below are the errors and the h and cpp files:

> Error 7   error C2371: 'Parser::parse' : redefinition; different basic
>   types c:\users\seb\documents\visual studio
>   2005\projects\TestDLL\TestDLL\parser.cpp  17
>
> Error 4   error C2526: 'Parser::parse' : C linkage function cannot
>   return C++ class 'std::vector<_Ty>'   c:\users\seb\documents\visual
>   studio 2005\projects\TestDLL\TestDLL\parser.h 28
>
> Error 6   error C2556: 'IDVec Parser::parse(const char *)' : overloaded
>   function differs only by return type from 'void Parser::parse(const
>   char *)'  c:\users\seb\documents\visual studio
>   2005\projects\TestDLL\TestDLL\parser.cpp  17

Also find the .h file and the function from the .cpp as well:

**Parser.h**

```
#ifndef PARSER_H
#define PARSER_H

#if defined DLL_EXPORT
#define TESTAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TESTAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef struct _ListEntry {
    std::string id, path;
} ListEntry;

typedef std::vector<ListEntry> IDVec;

extern "C"
{
    class TESTAPI Parser
    {
    public:
        Parser(void);
        ~Parser(void);
        static IDVec parse(const char* Buffer);
    private:
        static size_t nextLine(std::string& rstrText, size_t pos);
        static std::string nextWord(std::string& rstrText, size_t pos);
        static void fixOSSpecificPath(std::string& rstrPath);
    };
}

#endif
```

**Parser.cpp**

```
IDVec Parser::parse(const char* Buffer) 
{

    std::string s = Buffer;
    IDVec v;

    // Doing stuff here

    return v;
}
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: What do you expect to achieve by wrapping C++ class in `extern "C"` block? Also, if all the members are static, then why it's a class in the first place.

Comment: Get rid of `extern "C" linkage. There are no classes and member functions in C.

Comment: This is my first time making a DLL and I was just following a basic tutorial close to what they said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `extern "C"` around your class definition.

Comment: This did seem to work. I do have a follow-up question to this though. Most of the DLL creation tutorials show classes in an extern "C" block. Is there any use for this at all or is it not necessary.

Comment: That are some weird tutorials. Blindly wrapping C++ classes with extern "C" makes no sense. There is good explanation what extern "C" does here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/extern-c